# Increment values based on variable

Tags: sqlite

I have a table that looks like this :

```
DATE         user_id  amount_spent
2018-04-16    xxxx     0.99
2018-05-16    xcxc     5.10
2018-05-18    xdxd     4.99
2018-04-17    xvxv     7.00
...
```

I need to add another column called ID  that ranges for `1 to n` and that indicates, per user, the position of the purchase. 1 being the order of the 1st purchase and n the order of the last one.

So it would output something like that :

```
DATE         user_id  amount_spent   ID
2018-04-16    xxxx     0.99          1
2018-05-16    xcxc     5.10          2
2018-05-18    xdxd     4.99          4
2018-04-17    xvxv     7.00          3
...
```

So my code looks like this atm :

```
    ALTER TABLE temp_table
    ADD ID VARCHAR;

  UPDATE temp_table SET ID = (SELECT * FROM (WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(x) AS (VALUES(1) UNION ALL SELECT x+1 FROM cnt WHERE x< (select count(*) from temp_table))
SELECT x FROM cnt));
```

But then the `ID` isn't associated with the date and it only outputs 1 for every `ID`

Any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Use a [correlated subquery](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub) to count how many rows have a smaller date value:

```
UPDATE temp_table
SET ID = (SELECT count(*)
          FROM temp_table AS t2
          WHERE t2.DATE <= temp_table.DATE);
```

Alternatively, insert the rows into the temporary table with the correct ORDER BY, then the `rowid` values are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the code you wrote is showing me how many rows have the same date, but that's not what I am trying to acheive.

Comment: @Promap The solution looked right to me, so I checked it out. For the sample data you've provided, it seems to work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/1972c/1

Comment: @Promap That's not `=` but `<=`.

Comment: That's weird, because when I try the same code with my dataset, for ID, it outputs the last ROWID of the same date. For example, if I have 9 observations for 2018-04-16 then it outputs 9 for all of their ID. I know it must be my fault, like I omitted something in my explanation maybe. I'm sorry !

Comment: @Promap You did not have duplicate dates in the example data. The filter `t2.DATE <= temp_table.DATE` counts all rows with the same value, so in that case, you have to use the temporary table mechanism.